# Array initiation with flow-typed

Tags: arrays, flowtype

If there is an array declared as below:

```
let arr: Array<{name: string, age: number, gender: string}>;
```

Does this mean that in this array `arr`I have a list of objects with properties of `name`, `age`, and `gender` in it?

The way I am understanding this is such like:

```
let arr = [{name: string, age: number, gender: string}];
```

So that this array only store objects, and a valid output of the array if there are two obj in it will be something like:

```
[{name: "abc", age: 30, gender: "M"}, {name: "xyz", age: 15, gender: "F"}]
```

Im not sure if my understanding is right. Could someone explain a little bit more about the way it is implemented as `Array<{name: string, age: number, gender: string}>`?

Comment: "If there is an array initialized as below:" The code you show specifies the type of the array but does not actually initialize the array.

Comment: I think the correct term is "declared".  But I don't know if that's legal JavaScript.

Comment: Your understanding is correct

Comment: Note that this is not legal JavaScript syntax. It is some other language that is added to JavaScript for type checking.

Comment: Yea, the code is written with flow-typed. Which I am kind of confused, and trying to see if I understood it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Array<{name: string, age: number, gender: string}>
You are right , it means that variable will be an array of objects and object will be of format

```
{name: string, age: number, gender: string}
```

this